# Tool for documenting NuGet packages used in a solution

Tags: .net, build, continuous-integration, nuget

As part of a CI/build process, extracting information regarding a solution and making it available in a centralized place can be very useful.

I'm looking for a way to document what NuGet packages are used by a build, extracted to a text file of some sort (markdown would be ideal), to be part of the automatically generated build history.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at [`dotnet outdated`](https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated) - its primary focus is to update dependencies, but it lists all installed dependencies as well. Maybe you can make use of it.